# How to Upload Last Modified File **with the Name of the File** with FTP - VB - Still Missing Code-

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, last-modified

**There has been an EDIT to this title** 1:17:45 AM EST 12/29/13

Good Morning,

I'm currently working on a **solution to have a program upload the most recently modified file in a specific directory** to an online storage site, but I'm running into an issue specifying the most recently modified file in the directory.

I'm by no means a programmer, but I have recently been inspired to learn VB Script. All related articles I have reviewed include additional processes, but I can not seem to chop up the codes to use them successfully so I am hoping that someone could help me.

EDIT* There is no error message but I simply just do not know how to tell the program to upload the most recently modified file.

This is my first time posting on this site and the community here is great! Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("FTP://ftp.DRIVEHQ.COM/information.zip"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\Public\Documents\LAST MODIFIED FILE")

    Dim Strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    Strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
    Strz.Close()
    Strz.Dispose()
```

Also the extension of the file I am looking for will be a .zip. Any contributions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the problem or error you are getting?

Comment: If I specify the file the program works great. I am not getting an error message but I simply just do not know how to tell the program to select the last modified file at the location to be uploaded. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems that I overlooked something that was very important. I need the file to upload with the name it has been assigned as opposed to the pre-determined one I have set in the line below:`(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("FTP://ftp.DRIVEHQ.COM/information.zip"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)`
Any ideas on how to overcome this? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add the code I contributed to the top of the routine.  Then use fi.Name to get the file's name and use it when creating the ftp request.

Comment: Thanks again for your quick response but I'm not clear on where exactly to place it. Sorry to be a pain but is there any chance you can edit your previously submitted answer to include this functionality. If not I understand, but in the meantime I'll try it out.

Comment: I tried last night to put it all together how you said and it hasn't worked so far. I'll keep trying but I am terribly new at all of this.

Comment: I updated it.  Sorry for the delay. I've not been on SO for a few days.  I was busy on a project and vacation.

Comment: It is all good like always I seriously thank you for all your help. There is a warning in the software that says Variable 'fi' is used before it has been assigned a value, A null reference exception could result at runtime. 

Then the software crashes on the line "Strz.Close()" and the associated message says "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I got it to work! I moved the line "Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileToUpload)" to above the dim request and it worked properly. I tried to edit your answer to show this change but I couldn't get it to show up properly. I cannot thank you enough man, you are good person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently learned File navigation on a project that sends modified files to Azure.

Try this:

```
Imports System.IO

Dim Folder As String = "C:\User\Public\Documents\"
Dim Files() As String

'Find all zip files in folder
Files = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Dim fi As FileInfo

Dim FileToUpload As String = ""
Dim LastModifiedTime As DateTime = "1/1/1700"
For Each sFile In Files
    fi = New FileInfo(sFile)
    'Find the last mofified zip file
    If fi.LastWriteTimeUTC > LastModifiedTime Then
        LastModifiedTime = fi.LastWriteTimeUTC
        FileToUpload = sFile
    End If
Next

Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("FTP://ftp.DRIVEHQ.COM/" & fi.Name), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FileToUpload)

Dim Strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
Strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
Strz.Close()
Strz.Dispose()
```

Comment: It seems like the could should work for the most part but I'm getting an issue with the File in the line: "For Each File In Files".
The Error Message says: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Comment: I changed it to sFile so it doesn't conflict your other file() variable.

Comment: I cranked up Visual Studio and I was able to make it successfully find a file and upload it.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  You too!  I'm new to contributing to StackOverflow too.  it is actually fun and a nice way to break up the monotony of the day.  Could you please mark my answer as the Answer if it did the trick for you?

Comment: I'm getting an error message after I attempt to click the button that starts it:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled
  Message=Could not find a part of the path 'C:\User\Public\Documents\'.

Comment: Thing is I know that location is valid so its confusing a bit. I'm glad I can spice up your day haha.

Comment: Try C:\Users\Public\Documents.  Users with an "s"

Comment: I am also working in a call center so I apologize for the lapse of time. when I changed it to the path you mentioned it says "Access to the path 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\My Music\' is denied." More details mention "Source=mscorlib", not sure if that helps.

Comment: So I tested it with a folder on my desktop and it worked perfectly! Your the best man, hope you have a great weekend.

Comment: It seems that I overlooked something that was very important. I need the file to upload with the name it has been assigned as opposed to the pre-determined one I have set in the line below:`(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("FTP://ftp.DRIVEHQ.COM/information.zip"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)`
Any ideas on how to overcome this? Any advice is greatly appreciated!